# #import functions into multiple source files

Tags: xcode, ios, header, import

I have a header (`.h`) file that I've defined a bunch of mathematical functions in, for example this one that calculates atmospheric refraction...

```
float calcAtmosRefraction(float h0) {
    float ref = 0.0;
    if (h0 > 85) {
        ref = 0.0;
    } 
    else if (h0 > 5) {
        ref = (58.1 / tan(degToRad(h0)) - 0.07 / pow(tan(degToRad(h0)), 3) + 0.000086 / pow(tan(degToRad(h0)), 5)) / 3600;
    }
    else if (h0 > -0.575) {
        ref = (1735 + h0 * (-518.2 + h0 * (103.4 + h0 * (-12.79 + h0 * 0.711)))) / 3600;
    }
    else {
        ref = -20.772 / tan(degToRad(h0)) / 3600;
    }
    return ref; // in degrees
}
```

... and in my main `UIViewController's` implementation file I use `#import` to add the header.  It works fine and I can use the functions.  The problem occurs when I want to use these functions in a different `UIViewController.`  If I don't `#import` the header, I get an `implicit declaration` warning for the function name, and if I do `#import` the header, I get a `duplicate symbol` error.

Comment: atmospheric refraction? boy am I interested in what this app does now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is to use a combination of a `.h` and a `.m` file:

Your `.h` should look like this:

```
extern float calcAtmosRefraction(float h0);
```

And your `.m` should have what you have above. `#import` the `.h` file and you'll be good to go.

Another way you can do this is make the function `static` so it doesn't get redeclared. This approach allows you to use only one `.h` file.

Comment: That makes sense, it's just like my other `.h/.m` file pairs - the `.h` declares stuff and the `.m` implements it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your function is defined in the header (and it doesn't have a definition that lives elsewhere), then declare it `static` or `inline`.

You're getting a duplicate symbol error because C and C++ (and by extension, Obj-C and Obj-C++) disallow multiple definitions of a single function. Either `static` or `inline` will eliminate the multiple definition error.